# Запрос к MySQL из Delphi

Tags: delphi, mysql

Каким образом можно объединить MySQL и delphi 7? Надеюсь, что я правильно задал вопрос. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

А еще есть нормальный [ODBC драйвер](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) для MySQL, с которым можно работать стандартными средствами типа TADOConnection.

Answer (score 1):

Объединить вряд ли получится. А вот клиент-серверное приложение вполне удастся. Смотрите специальные компоненты типа DataSet и тд. Есть еще MySQLQuery (вроде так называется) когда 7 версию делфи ломали, то этот компонент у большинства пользователей стал не рабочим - все ушли на DataSet. Хотя в Делфи 6 - все компоненты работают отлично.

Comment: А как будет выглядеть конечный результат, т.е после объединения? К примеру, у меня что в delphi появятся новые вкладки и каждый раз, когда я буду открывать delphi, я смогу просматривать базу с MySQL или для того, чтоб просмотреть базу мне надо будет постоянно проводить ту или иную операцию (вытаскивать компоненты) для просмотра базы? Спасибо.

Comment: Так вам базу просмотреть нужно в Delphi или написать программу на Delphi, работающую с MySQL?

Comment: все я справился, спасибо. вытащил компонент SimpleDataSet, datasource, mySQL connection button и dbgrid.

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов много:

1. на прямую - пишете библию для дллки мускула,
2. через перемычку, например ZEOSDBO,
3. через язык посредник (что я и предпочитаю), например пхп.